# Changing button data-theme dynamically in JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having a little trouble dynamically changing a button's theme dynamically.  From a different post I learned to use:

```
<input type="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" id="my-button" value="Save">
<script>
$("#my-button").buttonMarkup({ theme: 'a' }).button('refresh');
</script>
```

Technically this works, until I mouse over - then the button falls back to data-theme "c".  Is there a better way to dynamically change theme?

Answer (score 1):

if you use a button as below

```
 <a href="#" id="my-button2" data-role="button" data-theme="e">Save2</a>
```

You can change the theme as below

```
$('#my-button2').attr("data-theme", "c").removeClass("ui-btn-up-e").addClass("ui-btn-up-c");
```

check out a live fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/jfDLU/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the answer for this one, but came up with this solution after looking into the DOM structure. I created the below function for toggling the theme on click the button. the hover class needs to be addressed only when changing the theme of the same button you are clicking.
These seems to work for input type button element. (jqm version 1.3.2)

```
function changeButtonTheme(buttonSelector,toTheme){
    var currentTheme  = $(buttonSelector).attr('data-theme');
    var parent  = $(buttonSelector).parent();
    $(buttonSelector).attr("data-theme", toTheme).removeClass("ui-btn-up-"+currentTheme).addClass("ui-btn-up-"+toTheme);
    parent.attr("data-theme", toTheme).removeClass("ui-btn-up-"+currentTheme).addClass("ui-btn-up-"+toTheme);
    //parent.removeClass("ui-btn-hover-"+currentTheme).addClass("ui-btn-hover-"+toTheme);
}
```

Comment: I didn't test yet it, but I think your code would only change the btn-up state.  There are still event handlers in memory that would change it to the old state on hover or mouse down.  I could be wrong, though..